# Redirect URL with Regex removing £ symbol to PaypalMe

Tags: javascript, regex, .htaccess, cpanel

I am looking for a regex option to use with htaccess.

I need to strip out a £ symbol from any url and then redirect to another domain whilst maintaining the parameter that was after the £ symbol

So

```
example.com/£7.50
```

gets redirected to

```
paypal.me/myid/7.50
```

This was the htaccess that redirects ONLY example.com/£7.50

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exmaple\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9] 
{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^\Â\£7\.50$ "https\:\/\/paypal\.me\/myid\/7\.50" [R=301,L]
```

I have tried some of the options in
https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489
with no joy. Any ideas?

*So anything with a £ symbol in the URL, needs the £ removing and redirecting to Paypal.me with my id and numeric value appended.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the working code in the end

```
RewriteRule ^\Â\£\/?(.*)$ "https\:\/\/paypal\.me\/myid\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^£(.*)$ {NEW DOMAIN ADDR}/$1 [R=302, NC]
```

Comment: Tried your example and RewriteRule ^£(.*)$ "https\:\/\/paypal\.me\/myid\$1" [R=301,L] with no joy

Comment: Try it like this _RewriteRule ^£(.*)$ https://paypal.me/myid/$1 [R=301, L]_

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^£(.+)$ https://paypal.me/myid/$1 [R=301,L]
```